# Reading a string in C++ using scanf

Tags: c++, string, char, scanf

I am trying to read a string in C++ using scanf. I tried

```
char cmd[40];
scanf("%s", cmd);
string str(cmd);
```

But this gets me a string I want to have plus some non-sense characters.

Comment: Make sure you are entering no more then 40 symbols

Comment: I'm not. C++ is adding characters so that there is 40 of them.

Comment: Why scanf in C++? Also use limited scanf string, so you cannot run out of the preallocated array.

Comment: Speed issues. As far as I know, scanf is way faster than std::cin.

Comment: What is your test input, and what are you getting out? Because I definitely cannot replicate this.

Comment: [*Can NOT reproduce.*](http://ideone.com/iuYAP7)

Comment: Actually, make sure you are entering no more than 39 symbols... Need to leave room for the terminating `\0`...

Comment: @twalberg OK even for longer input: http://ideone.com/Ww9DKz

Comment: @user2062607: I would use `std::cin` even if I knew it was slower, mostly because you can avoid all sorts of issues, probably including this one.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Just because your program doesn't immediately crash and burn when you input a string longer than the 39 bytes plus terminator space you've allocated doesn't mean it's right. That's bona fide undefined behavior there... You just got lucky.

Answer (score 6):

`scanf` with the `%s` specifier will store a null terminator after the input string which prevents garbage characters from getting into the string... unless your code has undefined behavior.

Your issue is likely that the input is overflowing the buffer, resulting in undefined behavior; When using the `%s` specifier without an appropriate buffer size `scanf` may write outside the bounds of the buffer. At that point you have no guarantees about how the program will behave.

Never use `%s` with `scanf` wihtout providing a buffer size:

```
char cmd[40];
scanf("%39s", cmd);
string str(cmd);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I probably wasn't clear enough. I don't know the precise size of strings. I just know it's at most 40.

Comment: @user2062607: Make the buffer 41 then

Comment: @user2062607 The buffer size you give to scanf is the maximum it will read. If the input string is shorter then scanf will stop before then. As Mooing Duck says, if the string can be 40 char long then have a buffer of 41 char and tell scanf to read at most 40 char.